# Opening CRM Appointment Prompt by Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using the ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application") to show new appointment window. The item type is olAppointment (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869291(v=office.14).aspx).

Now customer really demands that it shouldn't be a default appointment but CRM Appointment item. Is there any way that if user has Outlook CRM Plugin installed that it would be possible?

The code:

```
this.setAppointment = function (data) {
try {
    out = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
    appt = **out.CreateItem(1);** //here I'd love to have CRM Apointment type
    appt.Subject = data.Subject;
    appt.Location = data.Location;
    appt.Start = formatDateForOutlook(data.Start);
    appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = data.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart;
    appt.Display();
} catch (err) {                 
    if (console && console.error) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        alert(err);
    }
}
        }
```

When I'm saying "CRM Appointment item" I mean this view
[image: Desc]

EDIT:

I've just found out that the only thing I need to do is to automatically set "Regarding" field. So it would be great if I could do something like:

```
this.setAppointment = function (data) {
   try {
    out = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
    appt = **out.CreateItem(1);** //here I'd love to have CRM Apointment type
    appt.Subject = data.Subject;
    appt.Location = data.Location;
    appt.Start = formatDateForOutlook(data.Start);
    appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = data.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart;
    appt.RegardingObjectId = { Id: {guid}, LogicalName: "EntityName" } //Ofc it's not working because of error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" 
    appt.Display();
  } catch (err) {                   
        if (console && console.error) {
        console.error(err);
  } else {
        alert(err);
  }
```

}
                }

any help or advice or workaround will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
appt.RegardingObjectId = { Id: {guid}, LogicalName: "EntityName" }
```

What sort of object are you trying to make a reference to? if it was a case it should be

```
appt.RegardingObjectId = { Id: {guid}, LogicalName: "incident" }
```

and soforth and so on. The regarding object needs to know what entity the ID belongs to.

EDIT: also, you can pull the entity name from javascript using something like this

```
entityname = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("<FIELD>").getValue()[0].typename;
```

Comment: I tried with "incident" but still no luck. The problem is as I assume that, this ActiveXObject just doesn't support this and I won't be able to make it happen